Spinor representation for indefinite signature
Recall that for a $n$-dimensional vector space with positive definite quadratic form, we have the spin representation thanks to the following inclusions
$$\Delta_n : \mathrm{Spin}(n) \rightarrow{} \mathrm{Cl}(n) \rightarrow{} \mathbb{C}\mathrm{l}(n) \rightarrow{} \mathrm{End}(\Delta_n) $$
where $$\Delta_n  = \mathbb{C}^{2^{\lfloor{n/2 \rfloor}}}$$
This map is fundemental because it tells us how to realize spinors as a clifford module (allowing us to make sense of Dirac matrices), and tells us how to transform spinors under $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ frame changes.
How do you extend this to indefinite signature? For example, $\mathrm{Spin}(1,3)$?

As far as I know it's basically the same. You construct the Clifford algebra, it has the indefinite spin group sitting inside it, etc.

Makes sense. Then I am mainly wondering about the role of complexification for the indefinite case: there is an isomorphism $\mathbb{C} l(s+t) \cong \mathrm{Cl}(s,t) \otimes \mathbb{C}$  Apparently this implies complex representations of $Cl(s,t)$ are equivalent (what does this mean?) to complex reps of $\mathbb{C}l(s+t)$. Given that this makes sense, then we have something like $\tilde{\Delta}_n : \mathrm{Spin(1,3)} \to \mathrm{Cl}(1,3) \to \mathrm{Cl}(1,3) \otimes \mathbb{C} \to \mathrm{End}(\Delta_n)$

Yes, that's right. Concretely, the point is that after complexification we can replace a generator $e$ by $ie$, which squares to $-e^2$, so complexification ignores the signature. So we get isomorphic complex Clifford algebras and they have the same representations.
